# .Net Framework 2.0 Setup not running on XP

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a Winforms application using Visual Studio 2013 targeting .Net framework 2.0. After creating the setup, I tested it on Windows 7 machine where it is running fine but when I try to install this setup on machine having Windows XP OS, it throw exception that .Net framework 4.5 is required. I have verified from the Dependencies in Setup that the initial requirements are .Net framework 2.0 only. Not sure, why this problem is coming. Any suggestions.

Comment: Using the unsupported .vdproj installer?  Look at the file with Notepad and you'll see the problem.  You can edit out the LaunchCondition but it will put it right back when you make any changes.  Well, that's why it is unsupported.

Comment: yes, you are right. I saw that and it specifies the version 4.5, so, what is the solution now ? what should I do to make it run on Windows XP?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use a different installer if you want to target Windows XP.  From the linked question it appears that InstallShieldLE, which is free, still works on Windows XP.